# Macro for coloring cells in a financial model

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro for changing the font color of cells based on their type. The code looks like this

```
Sub ModelColoring()

Dim cell As Range, constantCell As Range, formulaCells As Range
Dim cellFormula As String

With Selection
On Error Resume Next
    Set constantCell = .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlNumbers)
    Set formulaCells = .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, 21)
On Error GoTo 0
End With


If Not constantCell Is Nothing Then
    constantCell.Font.Color = vbBlue
End If

If Not formulaCells Is Nothing Then
For Each cell In formulaCells
    cellFormula = cell.Formula

    If cellFormula Like "*.xls*]*!*" Then
        cell.Font.Color = RGB(0, 176, 80)
    ElseIf cellFormula Like "*!*" _
    And Not cellFormula Like "*\**" _
    And Not cellFormula Like "*+*" _
    And Not cellFormula Like "*-*" _
    And Not cellFormula Like "*/*" _
    And Not cellFormula Like "*^*" _
    And Not cellFormula Like "*%*" _
    And Not cellFormula Like "*>*" _
    And Not cellFormula Like "*<*" _
    And Not cellFormula Like "*=<*" _
    And Not cellFormula Like "*=>*" _
    And Not cellFormula Like "*<>*" _
    And Not cellFormula Like "*&*" Then
        cell.Font.Color = vbRed
    Else
    cell.Font.Color = vbBlack
    End If
Next cell
End If

End Sub
```

I am having problems with this line

```
And Not cellFormula Like "*\**"
```

Basically I want all the cells with constants have one font color, those  that perform a calculation to have another and those that derive their value from another sheet a third. However, the above mentioned line does not seem to recognize the multiplication symbol * for some reason and colors the cells that use values from other sheets and multiply them as if they are simply derived from another sheet (i.e. vbRed instead of black).

Comment: You need to prefix the asterisk with a tilde (e.g. ~) character to force Excel to explicitly look for an asterisk and not to treat the asterisk as a wildcard.

Comment: So the correct line would be like this?

    And Not cellFormula Like "*~**"

Comment: Did you already tried @AntiDrondert suggestion?

Comment: Yes I did, but it did not help.